# Drupal 7 Services JSON shows fields names with spaces

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7

I have drupal 7 deployment with services 3 module.  I have Services with JSON output configured.  When I get my results, the custom fields return labels instead of the actual field names.  For example, Node Title which is built in shows node_title.  However, 1 Year a custom field that was stored as field_1_year shows up as 1 Year.  This makes it difficult to parse JSON.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm always using my custom made feeds. A little more work, but full output control.

Comment: @MilanG - thanks.  Do you have a sample code posted somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your custom json feed i.e.:

- Make you php script and at top add standard D7 bootstrap:

  define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

After this code you'll have all Drupal's functionalities available in your script.

- Add your code to get values you want. You can use Drupal's database api, or even easier, create some view and use views_get_view_result() function to get values view returns:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

- Then iterate trough your results and create another php array containing values you want in the way you want.
- Use json_encode to convert your array to json string:
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- Print out your json string. You can even print out json header before it, so apps that are getting feed will know it's json (sometime may be needed)

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Something like that...